# Why toLowerCase() does not work with a regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, lowercase

This:

```
replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z]+)/g,'$1'+'$2'.toLowerCase() )
```

Does not convert $2 to lowercase (unchanged)

But :

```
replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z]+)/g,'$1'+'heLLo'.toLowerCase() )
```

Makes every upper case being replaced by "hello" (as expected)

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a callback

Comment: Check the following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pGp36/). `r0` is group 0, which means the whole matched string. That's why we added it so we could use `r1` and `r2`. Enjoy

Comment: @HamZa - +1 - should probably post that code here as an answer.

Comment: @ridgerunner I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate somewhere. I searched but couldn't find a decent one ...

Answer (score 2):

Because `toLowerCase` is executed before it gets in the main function `replace`. This is what you are doing:

```
replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z]+)/g,'$1hello')
```

You can do what you want with this:

```
var replaceLogic = function(fullMatch, firstGroup, secondGroup){ 
    return firstGroup.toLowerCase() + secondGroup; 
};
string.replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z]+)/g, replaceLogic);
```

Comment: You can't do it with replace. You will need another aproach like store the position of the letters to lowercase and then iterate over them. Should exist better ways, I think.

Comment: +1 - This does correctly answer the specific question asked. (But you are wrong about not being able to do this with `String.replace()` - see HamZa's comment.)